# How to export node tree to mtl

Tags: materials, node-editor, export, obj, three.js

I created a nice "Pattern" using the node editor,

When I try to export it to .obj and .mtl file

and use it in website, using [Three.js](https://threejs.org/).

But I found my nice pattern were gone, only the basic color left.

What should I do ?

What I am trying to do is to create a generic model, and a set of materials to apply

Comment: You cannot properly export a node based material from Blender with all features like the original material.

Comment: Currently I am baking the material into image, but lighting is an issue... my material mostly based on roughness

Comment: As stated in multiple answers across Blender Stack Exchange, many softwares (and Blender is no exception) and render engines have specific features that are strongly related to this particular engine/software and cannot simply be transferred. Even within Blender itself, depending on which render engine you use, Cycles or Eevee, not all options and nodes are available in both, neither do they always look the same even though they are available for both. If you then use some other renderer like LuxRender or Octane etc. you have to create different materials for them as well.

Comment: If you're exporting to three.js, the best option would be to use Principled BSDF materials — with baked textures — and export to glTF. You can find examples of the materials supported for export in the [Blender glTF addon documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html). Properties like roughness and metalness are supported in glTF, but not in OBJ/MTL.